# Changing Cloud Service of a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I created a VM in Azure and attached a cloud service (`abc1.cloudapp.net`) to it. So I'm able to ssh into the machine using this cloud service. Now for some reason I want to change it to (`xyz.cloudapp.net`).

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the alias for the cloud service. You will need to drop it and create a new one.

I suggest redirecting your original domain the VIP Azure provides so you have a consistent domain name all the time.